# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException when making an insert to a database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm making a inserting program for database ..

I've simply a textbox to insert an article into my webpage.

When i insert this article:

> But while the results are pretty exciting, it's important to note that
>   this is still a small-scale study and further research is needed to
>   confirm the link between SERT and SAD, as well as the role that
>   sunlight plays on serotonin.
>
> The next step will be to find out more about why some people increase
>   SERT production as the days get shorter, and why some people are
>   unaffected. It’s estimated SAD affects more than 12 million people
>   across northern Europe.
>
> Sam Challis, an information manager at British mental health charity
>   Mind, told the BBC: "We don't yet know enough about how serotonin
>   levels can be affected by light levels so this is quite an
>   interesting, albeit small, study. We would welcome more research."

after updating that article into database ..it's throwing an error as:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's important to note 
that this is still a small-scale study and further researc' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
    at org.apache.jsp.controller.rajendra.arora.successfully_jsp._jspService(successfully_jsp.java:71)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1012)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:642)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've this code to insert into database:

```
    String content=request.getParameter("content");
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/news", "root", "1234");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into main_news(my_news) values('"+content+"')");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Surely, Help would be appreciated!

Comment: escape special characters (like ') - better use _PreparedStatement_ or you are prone to sql-injection...

Comment: Yeah i used something like this into my `(?)` .. but it's says error .. `setString(int, String)`

Comment: Replace `Statement` by [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). If you still encounter some problems, edit the post later.

Comment: The main purpose of SQL don't mess up a code with data.

Answer (score 2):

As DaniEll said, that is because your string contains single quotes (`'`). To prevent this problem you can use `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement
      ("insert into main_news(my_news) values(?)");
ps.setString(1,content);
ps.executeUpdate();
```